# Python Summing A 2D Array In Steps Defined With Element Number Range

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, 2d

```
import Numpy as np

a = np.array([[5, 1, 8, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2],[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]])
n = 2
[(a[0:2, i:i+n]).sum(axis=1) for i in range(0,a.shape[1],n)]
```

The output is:

```
[array([6, 5]), array([9, 5]), array([7, 7]), array([5, 6])]
```

How can I get a 2D array instead of 4 arrays I got in above output...Is there a better more elegant way doing this using reshape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always stack the results to get a single array:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[5, 1, 8, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2],[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]])
n = 2
np.stack([(a[0:2, i:i+n]).sum(axis=1) for i in range(0,a.shape[1],n)])
```

Giving you:

```
array([[6, 5],
       [9, 5],
       [7, 7],
       [5, 6]])
```

Alternatively, you can reshape the array and sum:

```
a.T.reshape(-1, n, 2).sum(axis=1)
```

Giving the same result. But note, the array will need to be reshape-able to the given `n`, so `n=4` is fine `n=3` is an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

a = np.array([[5, 1, 8, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]])
n = 2

out = sliding_window_view(a, (n, n)).sum(axis=n+1)[:, ::n].squeeze()
```

Output:

```
array([[6, 5],
       [9, 5],
       [7, 7],
       [5, 6]])
```

Comment: I'm curious — the OP's code works when `n=4` but this solution gives an error in that case. Can that be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

a = np.array([[5, 1, 8, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2],[2, 3, 4, 1, 6, 1, 4, 2]])
n = 2

print(sliding_window_view(a, (n,n))[:,::n].sum(axis=n+1))
```

Prints:

```
[[[6 5]
  [9 5]
  [7 7]
  [5 6]]]
```

Comment: Use `n` instead of 2 :-) I was faster this time :-P